# Event after pressing one key twice in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

Almost every game that uses "WASD" keys for char navigation, use "A + A" and "D + D" key combinations for running left and right.

So my character is able to walk but I don't see any good running implementation in Godot.

How to implement playing of running animation when user is pressing one key twice?

upd:
why it's not working?

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var move_speed: float = 200
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

var run_state = false

func test():
    var turned_right = velocity.x > 0
    var turned_left = velocity.x < 0
    
    if turned_right && run_state == false:
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "walk"
        var run_state = true
    elif turned_right && run_state == true:
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "run"



func _physics_process(delta):
    var input_direction = Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left"),
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_down") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up"))
    velocity = input_direction.normalized() * move_speed
    
    if velocity.length() > 0:
        $AnimatedSprite.play()
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")

    test()

    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Comment: I'm no expert but trying checking if the user has lift up the key and set a timer for maybe 0.1 seconds and if the user has pressed the key again within that time then start the running animation (or maybe use `shift + A` for running?)

Comment: Any idea how to programmatically do that, @cak3_lover?

Comment: @rokejulianlockhart I posted an answer, hopefully this is what you're looking for

Comment: That's incredible. Thank you, so much, @cak3_lover.

Comment: (For posterity, it's https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206715/9731176)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed everything myself.

Here's the working code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var speed = 200
var run_state = false

func _process(delta):
    var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1

    if velocity.length() > 0:
        velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
        $AnimatedSprite.play()
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")
    
    position += velocity * delta
    
    var turned_right = Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right")
    
    if turned_right && run_state == false:
        $Timer.start()
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "walk"
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
        run_state = true
    elif turned_right && run_state == true:
        $Timer.start()
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "run"
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
        run_state = false

func _on_Timer_timeout():
    run_state = false
```

Still have no clue why the code above didn't work.
And this way of doing a simple tasks like "D + D" is pain in ass

Answer (score 2):

This is what I could come up with from the top of my head but I'm sure there's a better implementation:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity:Vector2
export var gravity_speed=3000
export var jump_speed=-1000
export var walk_speed=200
export var run_speed=900
export var double_tap_delay=0.5
export var stop_delay=0.2
var press_count=0
onready var press_timer=$Timer

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    # Horizontal
    velocity.x=Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    velocity.x*=run_speed if press_count==2 else walk_speed
    
    # Jumping
    if(is_on_floor()):
        if(Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up")):
            velocity.y+=jump_speed
    
    # Gravity
    velocity.y += gravity_speed * delta
    velocity=move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP)
    
    
    # Double Press Check
    if(velocity.x):
        if(Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right") || Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left")):
            press_count=clamp(press_count+1,0,2)
        
        press_timer.wait_time=double_tap_delay
        
        if press_count==2:
            press_timer.stop()
        elif(!press_timer.time_left):
            press_timer.start()
    
    elif(!press_timer.time_left && press_count):
        press_timer.wait_time=stop_delay
        press_timer.start()

func _ready():
    press_timer.one_shot=true
    press_timer.connect("timeout",self,"set",["press_count",0])
```

Your tree should look something like this:

[image]

and yes I agree implementing `D+D` is definitely a *pain in the ass*
better to use `Shit + D`

**Note:** This is done in version 3.5 probably won't work in godot 4